# C loop unrolling limitations?

Tags: c, optimization

I am performing optimizations on C for-loops, and I just read up on unrolling and accumulators. If data is not dependent of eachother in the loop, the use of unrolling and accumulators really takes advantage of parallelism, and the code finishes faster.

So my naive thought was, *why not add more accumulators and unroll more times?*

I did this, and noticed that there was diminishing returns in the reduction of average cycles per element.

My question is **why?**

A: Is it because we are running out of registers to work with simultaneously, and information needs to be stored in memory?

B: Or is it because the 'cleanup loop' has to process more elements after the unrolled loop?

Is it a combination of A and B?

Comment: Don't forget that unrolling puts a greater burden on the instruction cache.

Comment: Isn't L1 instruction cache large enough to handle 16 unsigned ints? As I go from 8 to 16 accumulators/unrolls, the benefit is negligible.

Comment: @filposs: The trace cache is certainly not. I think it only fits some 50-100 µops.

Comment: By "diminishing returns", don't you actually mean that it's going slower after a while? Otherwise, what were you expecting, really? That the loop would just keep going faster and faster forever the more you unroll? (Normally, "diminishing returns" means that you gain less and less, not that it's getting worse.)

Comment: @Dolda2000 yes, by "diminishing returns' I mean that there is less and less benefit.

Comment: @filposs: I cannot but wonder what you were expecting, then. Did you expect each loop "iteration" to just go faster and faster the more you unrolled it, until it reached zero time?

Comment: @Dolda2000 I never said I expected anything. My question is in bold above. Care to answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm just stating the obvious here, but the *main* reason why you're seeing diminishing returns from unrolling is simply because you've largely eliminated the overhead from the loop, and the remaining time on the CPU is spent almost entirely in the "useful" work that you're doing.

The benefit of unrolling is that you're eliminating the overhead of the loop itself -- that is, index increment, comparisons, branching, &c. -- not that it makes the useful work of the loop any faster. When you've reached the point where the loop overhead is mostly eliminated, it should be obvious that you aren't going to see further improvements from more unrolling.

On the other hand, there are certainly some aspects of further unrolling that makes performance worse, such as registers spilling to memory, the I-cache working less efficiently, the loop being too large for the trace-cache (on processors that sport such), &c.

Comment: Obvious for you, not-so-obvious for a beginner. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed that would be the first paragraph of whatever material you were reading. :)

Answer (score 1):

More likely, A. I've seen that not much time ago. I did myself the same question and the conclusion I reached was that I ran out of registers so no more fast accumulators. The clean-up code to process the rest of elements not unrolled run for much less time that the main unrolled loop.

Comment: What exactly happens when you run out of registers? I'm new to the hardware side of things. It doesn't get stored in DRAM, correct? because it takes ~1000 cycles to retrieve something from DRAM. Does our info get stored in some cache closer to the processor?

Comment: @fliposs: Yes, typically.  Most processors these days have L1, L2, and L3 cache before they have to go out to main memory.  Here's an interesting talk to get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE

Comment: When the compiler runs out of registers to store variables, it simply uses memory locations. What happens at the hardware level, variables ending up stored into DRAM, cache o even virtual memory in a disk, is of no concern for the compiler. The programmer can suggest, and in some case force, a variable to be stored in a CPU register by adding the keyword `register` in its definition.

Comment: writing register value back to memory and reading it back is pretty costy. on modern machines we are talking about 5-10 cycle each way even under ideal cache hit conditions. unrolling the loop doesn't directly cause excessive use of register, but it causes huge loop body that gives the compiler a real hard time on managing register lifetimes.